# Vagrant and Docker nfs failed: Bad file descriptor

Tags: macos, vagrant, boot2docker, nfs, vagrantfile

After a lot of review trying to use **rsync** in Vagrant with Docker as provider. (bidirectional sync)
I moved on to use **nfs** to sync my files inside the VM boot2docker

I have this vagrant error message after `vagrant up`

```
dockerhost: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 192.168.50.1:'/Users/myMac/workspace/docker-vagrant/test' /project

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

mount: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = No route to host
mount: mounting 192.168.50.1:/Users/myMac/workspace/docker-vagrant/test on /project failed: Bad file descriptor
```

Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.box = "dduportal/boot2docker"
 config.vm.define "dockerhost"
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
 config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
 config.vm.synced_folder "../", "/project", type: "nfs"
...
```

My mac already have nfs because started up the service using `nfsd start`

In the Vagrant documentation recommend to use rsync but I didn't find a way to rsync from VM to my MAC and vice versa.

I'm using

- Mac Yosemite
- Vagrant 1.8.1
- VM dduportal/boot2docker

Comment: rsync is monodirectional ("one-time one-way" as per [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html)), so you cannot share files from the guest to the host with that.

Comment: Tks, I understand that.

Comment: I already fixed. I'm going to answer my question soon. https://github.com/dduportal/boot2docker-vagrant-box/issues/48#issuecomment-219209400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question directly on the dduportal/boot2docker project.

and this is the correct configuration if you have your custom Docker Host in different directory.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", mount_options: ["nolock", "vers=3", "udp"], id: "nfs-sync"
```

Reference:
https://github.com/dduportal/boot2docker-vagrant-box/issues/48